# What is the lower bound of number of degree 1 vertices of a tree with no degree 2 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Here is the question:

> Let $G$ be a tree with $n$ vertices, and no vertex in the tree has degree $2$. Find a function of $n$ that indicates the lower bound of the number of degree $1$ vertices in the tree.

with handshake lemma and Euler's formula, I get $n_1 =2 + \sum_{k =3}^{\infty} (k-2)n_k$ where $n_k$ is the number of degree $k$ vertices. However, this result cannot tell me the lower bound of $n_1$.

I guess the result is $n -\big\lfloor  \frac{n}{2} \big\rfloor$, but not sure how to prove this.

Please give me some hint, thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484941/tree-having-no-vertex-of-degree-2-has-more-leaves-than-internal-nodes